# How to exclude protected questions in the Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I just went to create a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/210718/questions-with-an-high-wiew-count-and-score-but-arent-protected?Score=150&AnswerCount=3&ViewCount=20000) where I wanted to exclude protected questions with`PostHistoryTypeId<>19`.

```sql
select
   Posts.Id as [Post Link], -- Question title.
   LEN(body) as [Description length], -- many Early question would only recieve downvotes if they were asked today.
   Posts.OwnerUserId as [User Link],
   Reputation as [User Reputation],
   Score as [Votes],
   AnswerCount as [Number of Answers],
   Posts.FavoriteCount as [Number of Stars], -- Some questions seems to be very helpfull :) .
   Posts.CreationDate as [Asked on], -- The older is the question, the more is the chance that flags on them can't get reviewed.
   Posts.LastActivityDate as [last activity], -- Similar effect as with Posts.CreationDate.
   Posts.LastEditDate as [modified on],
   Posts.ViewCount
from posts 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Users on Users.id = posts.OwnerUserId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN PostHistory on PostHistory.Id = Posts.Id
where ClosedDate IS NULL -- The question is not closed.
   AND PostHistoryTypeId<>19 -- The question is still not protected.
   AND Score>=##Score:int?150## -- Score:Minimal score of the question.
   AND AnswerCount>=##AnswerCount:int?3## -- AnswerCount:Minimal number of Answers.
   AND Posts.ViewCount>=##ViewCount:int?20000## -- ViewCount:Minimal number of Views.
group by Posts.id, Posts.OwnerUserId, body, Reputation, Posts.Score, Posts.FavoriteCount, Posts.AnswerCount, Posts.CreationDate, Posts.LastActivityDate, Posts.LastEditDate, Posts.ViewCount
order by LEN(body) asc;
```

But protected questions are included in the results.

Comment: @0x7fffffff : Sorry I thought such questions should be posted at Stack Overflow (since it more an SQL error question asking for code because of a descirbed error than a question about the result of a query). On the Data Explorer site, I saw (some mounth) I can ask such question on Stack Apps or Stack Overflow with the `DataExplorer`tag. Have you locked at the [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataexplorer?sort=newest)? Most questions are like this and some are mines with exactly the same purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PostHistory.Id` is a unique Id number for every single event. You were looking to use `PostHistory.PostId = Posts.Id`.

Past that, there can be any number of entries for a post in the PostHistory table. I'm not 100% familiar with how SQL joins work when there are multiple rows, but I would have just used a NOT EXISTS query to make sure there's not any PostHistory events that are protection events.

```
AND NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT Id FROM PostHistory
  WHERE PostHistory.PostHistoryTypeId = 19 AND PostHistory.PostId = Posts.Id
) -- The question is still no protected.
```

[Here's the query on Data Explorer.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/210736)

Keep in mind that this query would not then include questions which have been protected and then subsequently *unprotected* afterwards.

---

@[icktoofay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/210346/icktoofay) suggests a way to include those which have been unprotected by using a case, making protections count as +1 and unprotections count as -1. If it turns out to be 0, it is currently unprotected and if it turns out to be 1, it is currently protected.

```
AND COALESCE(
  (
     SELECT SUM(
       CASE PostHistory.PostHistoryTypeId
           WHEN 19 THEN 1
           WHEN 20 THEN -1
       END
     )
     FROM PostHistory WHERE PostHistory.PostId = Posts.Id
  ), 0
) = 0
```

Comment: To handle unprotection: `AND COALESCE((SELECT SUM(CASE PostHistory.PostTypeId WHEN 19 THEN 1 WHEN 20 THEN -1 END) FROM PostHistory WHERE PostHistory.PostId = Posts.Id), 0) = 0` (rather than the `AND NOT EXISTS` thing you have now)

Comment: @icktoofay I have some troubles at understanding it unformatted... May you write it in a detailed answer please?

Comment: @user2284570: animuson kindly put a formatted version in his answer, but at the risk of being redundant, it looks at each post and finds all of the history events associated with it. It then assigns a value of 1 for each protection and -1 for each unprotection, and NULL for other events. It then takes a sum of those (coalescing NULL to zero). Any unprotection -1 will cancel out a protection 1, and any imbalance at the end will yield a result not equal to zero. If it is equal to zero, there are no protections or every protection is cancelled out by an unprotection.