# Support automatic SQL code syntax colouring for dataexplorer questions

Tags: feature-request, design, syntax-highlighting

Many[data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer)are no longer acceptable on Stack Overflow and need to be asked on [this site](http://meta.stackexchange.com)
Unlike Stack Overflow, there is no syntax colouring, this appear more clearly when a question is migrated from SO: the syntax colouring is lost after migration.

So can we support automatic SQL code syntax colouring  when[data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer)is used as part of the exception?

Comment: Why would Meta (this site) need syntax highlighting? It is a site to support the entire network (Chess, Cooking, Lego and other non-technical sites included).

Comment: Data Explorer-specific questions were never on-topic for Stack Overflow, unless they are about the specifics of SQL syntax, not the specifics of the schema and contained data.

Comment: @Oded questions about the data explorer are on topic here and may contain SQL (but certainly not C/C++)

Comment: @ChrisF - sure, but those are the exception to the rule

Comment: @MartijnPieters : No, they are off-topic on Stack Overflow, even if this about [specfic SQL syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataexplorer) are no longer on-topic on [Stack OverFlow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237203/242800)

Comment: @Oded : So consider this as a part of [that exception](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237203/242800).

Comment: @user2284570: Questions about SQL syntax are on-topic. If the syntax happens to be used for the data explorer, then *that doesn't make them suddenly off-topic*.

Comment: @user2284570: You can ask questions about Transact-SQL, don't confuse that with questions about the Data Explorer schema.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : No, Otherwise [those](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23609014/2284570) [questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237203/242800) would be still on So.

Comment: @user2284570: That is **not a SQL syntax question**, that is a question **about the schema**.

Comment: I think it'd be sufficient to associate SQL highlighting with [tag:data-explorer]. In the meanwhile, you can use `<!-- language: lang-sql -->` to get highlighting on individual code blocks.

Comment: @Stijn : Yes me too. I don't really understand your comment. May you write a detailed example in an aswer please?

Comment: @user2284570 - see my edit to your question that was migrated.

Comment: @ChrisF : This doesn't look as beautiful as on Stack Overflow but this can be Ok.

Comment: @user2284570 that's because the question is tagged with [tag:sql]. The `<!-- language: lang-sql -->` in the question is unnecessary because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use[sql](/questions/tagged/sql)It will put highlighting on data-explorer question and their answers,whereas`<!-- language: lang-sql -->`is more suitable in answer of a question without[sql](/questions/tagged/sql).

Comment: Indeed, the feature already exist.

Answer (score 2):

As [Stijn suggested in his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237221/support-automatic-sql-code-syntax-colouring-for-dataexplorer-questions?noredirect=1#comment777612_237221) you can add:

> `<!-- language: lang-sql -->`

before the block of SQL to get the code highlighted.

As [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) questions are a very small percentage of question on the site (and of those, not all deal with actual SQL) there doesn't seem to be much need to have it done automatically.

Comment: @user2284570 because the question has the [tag:sql] tag which has the highlighting associated with it.